# Looping Limited API data in Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: foreach, azure-data-factory

I have an API which has a limitation on of only **100 lines of data per request**, however I want all the data from the API. I want to pull this data from source using the REST interface in Azure data factory pipelines and sink into an pre-made SQL table. I have made a successful connection to the API and I can copy data from the first 100 lines however I´m stuggling to find a way to:

**A) pull subsequent lines after pulling the initial 100 lines
B) append these lines to the original 100 lines
C) keep this loop going until theres no more lines**

I have looking into Looping options like "for each activity" however these dont seem to be exactly what im after. perhaps I need to combine the multiple copy data tiles with the for each? is anyone able to help with the above example

data source equals API
data type equals json (list of client data, dates, etc)
Source connection route equals REST interface in Azure data factory pipelines
Sink location equals SQL table

Answer (score 0):

If your **API page response has link to the next page**, then you can use [REST API pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) in copy activity.

As you mentioned that your data is an array of objects, you need to give the correct mapping as per the array.

First, Give the Pagination like below. For my API, `_links.next.href` keys consists of the next page link, so I have given it. You need to give your key of next page link. Give your SQL table in sink.

[image]

Give the mapping using **Advanced editor** and give the JSON array in the Collection reference.

[image]

If your JSON array, contains nested array or nested objects it generates an error, so check the **Map complex values to string** above. In target the complex values will be converted to string, and you need to flatten them back in SQL.

**Table created from pipeline:**

[image]

If your API don't have next page link in present page, then you can try the below approach.

> **A) pull subsequent lines after pulling the initial 100 lines B) append these lines to the original 100 lines C) keep this loop going until theres no more lines**

Using this approach, copy each response as JSON files to a temporary location in each iteration using copy activity.

After ForEach, take another copy activity outside ForEach activity and take the source of temporary location and use wild card file path to get every file data and in sink take another target JSON and use the `Merge files` option in it (Also select Array ob objects in the File pattern).

This will generate a final JSON file which consists of all API data. Take another copy activity and copy this data to the target SQL table.

You can go through this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbURwy2a8dM) by **@WafaStudies** to understand about iterating through pages in REST API.

`

Comment: thanks so much for this. I´ll give the links a read/watch and give what you say a try.